# How to measure the symmetry of the curve?

Tags: statistics, symmetry

In statistics, we can measure the symmetry by skewness, but if we have a curve, in other words, if we have a list of x and y values, how to measure the symmetry of its plot.

Comment: I have learned this, but can't remember it very well. I think [this](http://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/a3121120.nsf/home/statistical+language+-+measures+of+spread) is the way to solve it

Comment: Let us know if this was what you need

Comment: sorry, my internet connect is blocked yesterday, but I can't figure out the relationship between them